# Google Analytics in cross platform mobile application

Tags: android, ios, cordova, google-analytics

Am creating android and ios application with the help of sencha and phonegap. Planning to add google analytics in my application. Am confused which kind of property should be added in google analytics account. Is it 'All mobileapp data' and 'All Website data'?

Answer (score 2):

You will have to go with "All MobileApp Data".
 Go through this link :- https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/?hl=en